Connecting Path/Tube to a convex hull
So here we have our tube/path that we've created with offset points:
path(tube)
Now we are looking into connecting them so that convex hull that can be seen on this next picture is kind of connected smooth to the the path (yellow one), and just becomes a convex hull with the path that goes to the last yellow point to the right if that makes sense. Here is the image for it: \
Path and convexhull together
Is this even possible to do? For any clarification please leave a comment.
We havent really tried anything because we dont really have any idea where to start or what to look at, we've kinda look at connecting it to the centeroid of the convex hull, but that did not workout.
Here is what the updated goal is, to make it look something like the red line around the yellow convex hull:
Updated looks

An easy way to do it would be drawing a polygon connecting the dots. Then you give the polygon a very wide stroke the same color as the fill and  stroke-linejoin="round". for the transparency you can add opacity="0.whatever".

@enxaneta So im interesed in our case, we dont really have just a straight path as you can see, it has a lot of offset points where we route a curve trough to get that kind of blobby shape, will this still work for the convex hull as intended? I've updated the shape we would like it to be with the red line going around the yellow convex hull and the path.

Your question is not clear. Please update your question and add a code example.
